Expanding dataframe column into multiple columns
The data frame with a single column value looks like the following
------------------------
| value                |
|----------------------|
| col1,col2,col3,col4  |
| v1,v2,v3,v4          |
| v1,v5,v9,v11         |
|----------------------|

I would like to generate a similar dataframe in spark scala like the following
-----------------------------
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
|---------------------------|
| v1   | v2   | v3   | v4   |
|---------------------------|
| v1   | v5   | v9   | v11  |
|---------------------------|

One of the way I could think of is may be via generating a new df using withColumn(). However, I am wondering if spark has a better way of doing this.
PS - My initial attempt was to read a csv inside an uber jar in spark env however it looks like there is no easy way to read a csv inside jar as per Load CSV file as dataframe from resources within an Uber Jar

Why are you tagging csv? Is your df the result of reading a csv file? If so, then it seems like a good idea to check that process. Might be as easy as skipping the first row, and correcting the delimiter.

can split help?

so yeah I have a uber jar containing a csv file which I tried reading using spark.read().csv() however it looks like there is no easy way to read a csv stored inside uber jar (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101701/load-csv-file-as-dataframe-from-resources-within-an-uber-jar) so I read it using the way mentioned which has now stored all the columns in a single column along with headers.

@werner yeah split I am using currently as follows
  .withColumn("_tmp", split($"value", ","))
  .filter($"value" =!= "col1,col2,col3,col4")
    .select(
    $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("col1"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("col2"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(2).as("col3").cast(LongType),
    $"_tmp".getItem(3).as("col4")
  )


One possibility is to read the data out of the CSV file, make a Dataset[String] out of it, and then feed it into spark.read.csv:
src/main/scala/App.scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import scala.io.Source

object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("csv-from-resource").master("local").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val csv = spark.createDataset(Source.fromResource("data.csv").getLines().toSeq)
    spark.read.option("header", value = true).csv(csv).show
    spark.stop()
  }

}

src/main/resources/data.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4
v1,v2,v3,v4
v1,v5,v9,v11

build.sbt
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.18"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "spark-playground",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.5.1",
  )

stdout
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|  v1|  v2|  v3|  v4|
|  v1|  v5|  v9| v11|
+----+----+----+----+


it didn't worked in databricks notebook

this thing actually worked
val st = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/path/subpath/subpath1/file.csv")
val csv = spark.createDataset(scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(st).getLines().toSeq)
spark.read.option("header", value = true).csv(csv).show



It would be better to make sure that csv is in external storage system (e.g. HDFS, local file system). JAR files are intended to package code and libraries, not data. Keeping large dataset inside the JAR is not efficient because it is distributed across the cluster causing unnecessary replication of the dataset on each worker.
In your case simply reading csv from a file system with header option should be enough
spark.read.option("header", True).csv(path)


data is really small like 10-15 lines of CSV. Since the project is already spark based, I was wondering to just re-use csv and spark's inbuilt functions to get the expected results.

This is the way. Better than the accepted answer.
